# How does UISearchController work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uikit, uisearchcontroller

How does `UISearchController` do everything it does?

- How does it transform the `UISearchBar` into a navigation-bar-like view?
- How does it put the `UISearchBar` into another view hierarchy and restore it later?
- How does it do all this using the `UIViewController` presentation API?
- How does it only cover the presenting view controller’s view even on iPhone where all presented view controllers are fullscreen?

Can I make my own `UISearchController` without using private APIs?

Answer (score 1):

`UISearchController` creates a `UISearchBar` and in its internal `_connectSearchBar` method it calls a private method on `UISearchBar` `_setSearchController`. Then in the `UISearchBar`'s internal event methods, e.g. `_searchFieldBeginEditing` it first calls its public delegate method and then `[__searchController _searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:]` to allow the controller to also process the event. This is what enables the feature "you free to become the `UISearchBar`'s delegate".

Similarly, in `UISearchBar`'s text field begin editing it calls `UISearchController`'s `_searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` which calls `_performAutomaticPresentation` which uses the transition coordinator to animate the presentation.

In the `UISearchBar`'s `didMoveToSuperView` it calls `[__searchController _searchBarSuperviewChanged]` which first checks if its searchBar has been put on a `UITableView` and if so it configures its background colours, insets etc. for viewing.

Yes you could architect this all yourself, but not by subclassing `UISearchBar` as you'd do in Java, instead of inheritance which can get complex use ObjC's delegation pattern which enables a flatter class hierarchy. E.g. you'd have a controller class that take a `UISearchBar` in its init method, sets itself as its delegate, then uses delegate forwarding to allow the existing delegate methods to still get called to the outside public delegate. Here is an example except for a table view:

```
- (instancetype)initWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView = tableView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
    if(MHFProtocolHasInstanceMethod(@protocol(UITableViewDelegate), aSelector)){
        if([self.tableViewDelgate respondsToSelector:aSelector]){
            return self.tableViewDelgate;
        }
    }
    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if([self.tableViewDelgate respondsToSelector:_cmd]){
        return [self.tableViewDelgate tableView:tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateSelectionForCurrentVisibleDetailItem) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

The point of this pattern is subclasses of your controller are no longer required to call super to ensure everything still works as expected without the programmer being required to call super. Also it makes for much more reusable classes since it can work with any kind of search bar.